# How to encrypt and decrypt messages using Virgil security?

Tags: encryption, private-key, public-key

I am trying to integrate Virgil security in my basic chat application but it won't as needed.

While chatting 2 users say A and B. After both users logged in and have some communication between them. Now both users reload/logged out or logged in then old messages was sent was not able to decrypt as new private keys will be generated.
I so not want to stored the public and private key of users in database or in local storage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm Dim from Virgil. Let me help you with this use-case.

I prepared some additional information:

Steps #1 and #2 from Virgil Simple JS Demo (You’ve already seen it)

**Step #1. User Registration Step.**

[users register their Public Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaVEA.jpg)

At this step:

- You authenticate Alice
- After you successfully authenticated Alice, you give her a JWT to grant her access to Virgil’s Cloud APIs
- Alice generates her Private Key (2) -> stores her Private Key into Local Storage -> creates her Virgil Card
- Alice Publishes (3) her Virgil Card on Virgil Cards Service (She uses her JWT to do it).
- Then you authenticate Bob (User B): same story as Alice.

At the end, Alice and Bob have their own Private Keys and Virgil Cards (Public Key published into our cloud for users to find each other’s Public Keys).

**Step #2. Simple Communication (chat).**

[Simple e2e encrypted communication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JzCe.jpg)

At this step:

- Alice looks for & finds Bob’s Public Key at Virgil Cards Service (1)
- Alice loads her Private Key from her Local Storage in a browser
- Alice signs (with her Private Key) and encrypts (with Bob’s Public Key) a message and sends to Bob through your Application Server
- Bob receives the encrypted and signed message
- Bob goes to Cards Service to find Alice’s Public Key in order to verify her signature
- Bob loads his Private Key from his Local Storage and decrypts the message

**As a result**, Bob verified Alice’s signature and decrypted the Message from Alice.

And now, **comes the problem**: Alice decided to use another Browser (or a Device B), but she can’t encrypt Bob’s previous messages on the new device.

**Solution:** you should transmit her Previous Private Key from Device A to Device B. To do this in the most secure way:

- is to encrypt Private Key on a device A with some Additional Secret Key.
- transmit encrypted Private Key to Device B.
- use the same Additional Secret Key on Device B to decrypt the encrypted Private Key from Device A.

So, as you see you must use some special Additional Secret Key on both devices (some messengers do this with a QR code between the devices) to do it securely. To do it simpler though, we have a special tech for you to you generate the “Additional Secret Key” that will be the same on both devices. We call that Secret Key - a Brain Key. **Brain Key** - a strong cryptographic asymmetric key based on Alice’s PASSWORD.

You can find more information about this key here: https://developer.virgilsecurity.com/docs/java/use-cases/v1/brainkey

So now, let’s take a look at the next step.

**Step #3. Store your Private Key in the Cloud**

[store somewhere encrypted Private Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdKNy.jpg)

At this step:

- Alice enters her Password
- Alice generates a Brain Key from her password (1)
- Alice encrypts her Private Key with the Brain Key (2)
- Alice uploads her encrypted private key somewhere in Cloud (to your app’s backend/database)

**As a result**, Alice will have her encrypted Private Key in the cloud, that she used to chat with Bob.

**Step #4. Alice now uses her new Browser (or new Device)**

[transmit a Private Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pI6w.jpg)

At this step:

- Alice enters her Password (the same that she used previously for Brain Key generation).
- This generates her Brain Key (1)
- Alice downloads her encrypted Private Key from the Cloud / from your backend/database (2)
- Alice decrypts the encrypted Private Key with the Brain Key

**As a result**, Alice will get her Private Key on a Device B, that she used to chat with Bob on a Device A. This way, the chat conversation survived her device change.

Every time when Alice uses a new device, she can re-generate the same Brain Key and easily get her Private Key, the key that she uses on all her devices to chat with Bob.

Answer (score 3):

David from Virgil here. Thanks for the question and sorry for making you puzzled.

I believe the issue is: while the sample app generated user private & public keys both for Alice and Bob, published the public keys to our Cards service, it hasn’t saved the private keys anywhere. So, the private keys remained in the browser's local storage and as such, didn’t sync to other browsers/devices where your users have logged in next. So in lack of their private keys, your users weren’t able to decrypt their messages... This is a limitation of the sample app and we should fix that ASAP (task created).

In order to get the app working, I.e. make your users be able to log in from another browser and decrypt messages, they need to retrieve their respected private keys from a central location. Now, it'd be too lame for me to recommend to just save the user private keys to your database (and enable others to access it + decrypt your users' messages), so we created a technology called BrainKey to encrypt the user private key with a key that we derive from the user’s password. Similar approach how Apple uses your TouchID-derived key to encrypt your keychain.

This is what you need to do to make it work:

1. During user signup (on the client device), generate a private key for your user and publish the public key to our Cards service.
2. Then use the user's password to generate a BrainKey (which technically is a private key).
3. Generate the public key from the BrainKey and encrypt the user's previously (Step 1) generated private key.
4. Now, save this encrypted private key to your database for the user.

Every single time your user logs in with her password, re-generate the same BrainKey from her password, download the encrypted private key from your DB, decrypt it with the BrainKey and now you can use this key to decrypt all chat messages that were sent to her.

Here’s a reference and sample code for our BrainKey tech: https://developer.virgilsecurity.com/docs/javascript/use-cases/v1/brainkey

Does it make sense? Would you like to see a sample code that does it? If you join our Slack, we can chat real-time, I’m @dave: https://join.slack.com/t/virgilsecurity/shared_invite/enQtMjg4MDE4ODM3ODA4LTc2OWQwOTQ3YjNhNTQ0ZjJiZDc2NjkzYjYxNTI0YzhmNTY2ZDliMGJjYWQ5YmZiOGU5ZWEzNmJiMWZhYWVmYTM

​David

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do not want to used database storage. Is their any other mechanism which Virgil security provide then please let me know.

Comment: Yes, there's a solution to this, you can try our new tech called the BrainKey https://developer.virgilsecurity.com/docs/java/use-cases/v1/brainkey

Comment: I am building my application in JavaScript